# How to configure my HTML to use i18next?

Tags: html, node.js, express, internationalization, i18next

I have an application with nodejs, express and HTML on client side. I'd like to internalize my project using i18next. On nodejs side, it's ok, I required i18next and started it.

```
var i18n = require('i18next'),
app = express();
i18n.registerAppHelper(app);
i18n.init({lng: "en-US"}, function(t){
var trad = i18n.t("trad.key1");
console.log("trad = " + trad);
});
```

In console log, I have the traduction of translation.json to variable trad.key1. It is correct.

Know, the question: what I need to do to use i18next on client side, HTML page? I found some examples to do this, but using jQuery, and I don't use that.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's done.

On HTML file, I needed to reference i18next.js and init i18n, like below. On init i18n, I specified the correct translation.json, as can you see.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="i18next/i18next.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        i18n.init({
            lng: "en-US",
            resGetPath:"locales/__lng__/translation.json"
        },function(t) {
            var translate = i18n.t("var.key1");
        });    
    };
</script>
```

That's all.

Comment: what is the `__lng__` thing there?

Comment: same question here. Could you please share your example? thanks